# Std::map serialization or map to int* converter

Tags: c++, stl, mpi

I have some huge project with STL data structures like std::map and std::list. I would like to make it parallel via MPI.
As I understand, no way to simply send std::list via MPI. I saw boost has some functions to do it, but I would like to understand other ways.

Are any speed optimized ways to convert some large std::map (or std::list) into something like int* to send it via standard MPI interface and unpack it on peer side?
I appreciate for some links to read community experience.

Added later.
since no answer I tried following:
char *ptr must be long enough. Tested with MPI environment.

```
struct Phase : public TscTime {
    Phase() : funcId(0), uniqIdx(-1LL) {}
    long funcId;
    long long uniqIdx;
    long pack(char *ptr) const {
        long ssize = 0, ptrIt = 0;
        ptrIt += TscTime::pack(ptr+ptrIt);
        ssize = sizeof(funcId);  memcpy(ptr+ptrIt, &funcId, ssize);  ptrIt+=ssize;
        ssize = sizeof(uniqIdx); memcpy(ptr+ptrIt, &uniqIdx, ssize); ptrIt+=ssize;
        return ptrIt;
    }
    long unpack(const char *ptr) {
        long ssize = 0, ptrIt = 0;
        ptrIt += TscTime::unpack(ptr+ptrIt);
        ssize = sizeof(funcId);  memcpy(&funcId, ptr+ptrIt, ssize);  ptrIt+=ssize;
        ssize = sizeof(uniqIdx); memcpy(&uniqIdx, ptr+ptrIt, ssize); ptrIt+=ssize;
        return ptrIt;
    }
};
```

Comment: You can construct a vector and insert the elements of the list using insert like: `std::vector<T> v; v.reserve(l.size()); v.insert(v.begin(), l.begin(), l.end());`

Comment: have you tried anything, that proves you need a "speed optimized way"?

Comment: You can create any simple container (list, vector, deque) from a pair of iterators by simply passing them to the constructor: `std::vector<T> v(l.begin(), l.end())`.

Comment: BTW: Putting multiple statements into a single line is not a "speed optimized way". It only makes it harder to read. OTOH declaring and initializing constants in one statement instead of declaring them as variables, initializing them to zero and then overwriting them repeatedly would be an improvement, in particular in readability.